# Are there hand held radios for both Amateur and CB?

Tags: ht, citizens-band

Are there combo handheld radios for CB and amateur radio? If so, is it practical?

Answer (score 6):

No, there are not, because it is not legal to have a radio that can transmit in both CB and amateur radio bands.

To be legal, CB radios must be part 95 type accepted.  The FCC prohibits a device to be both part 95 type accepted and capable of being used in amateur radio frequencies.

Having said that, many amateur radios are also wide band receivers, and can receive CB.

Comment: well, that's the answer for the U.S. It hardly says whether such devices exist, just whether they can be sold with this functionality.

Comment: No such device exists in the US.  FCC is actually fairly rabid about going after anyone who imports or sells such a device, and it's not legal to modify one either or even sell a device that can be easily modified to do both.

Comment: Well, such devices do *exist*, they are just illegal to operate. But I don't want to mince words here – you answer OP's question, which really was "can such devices be had easily", and I guess that implies buying and operating them legally.

Comment: Other nations with Citizens' Band and Personal Mobile Radio listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens_band_radio